# Prove that a subset of an open set is an open set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\Omega, d)$ be a metric space. If $M \subset \Omega$ is an open set, and $A \subset \Omega$. I want to show that $A\cap M$ is an open set (in $\Omega$) without using the subspace topology.

I know that since $M$ is open, then for every $x\in M$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x, r) \subset M$. Then I write that for every $x \in A \cap M \Rightarrow x\in M \Rightarrow \exists r>0$ s.t. $B(x, r) \subset M$. I know that I should get $B(x, r) \subset A\cap M$ but don't know that to do next.

Comment: You want to prove that $A\cap M$ is open *where*? In $\Omega$? Or in $M$?

Comment: One can prove that, if we look at $A$ as a metric space (with the metric $d_{|A \times A}$), then $V \subseteq A$ is open (*in the metric space $A$*) if and only if $V= U \cap A$, where $U$ is an *open set in $\Omega$*. Is that fact what you want to prove?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: In $\Omega$, forgot to mention.

Comment: Then the statement is false. Take $\Omega=\Bbb R$, with the usual distance, $M=\Bbb R$, and $A=\{0\}$. Then $M$ is open, but $A\cap M$ isn't.